# Unique Solution to Equation in Two Variables & Possible Use of the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $g(x) : R \to R$ be a continuous function;

Consider the equation $ T(x,y) = y^3 -y^2 +(1+x^2)y - g(x)$

Show that for a given $x$ there exist a unique solution $y$ to the equation $T(x,y) = 0$.

What I've done:

Set $\bar{x}$, consider the polynomial given by $y^3 -y^2 +(1+\bar{x}^2)y -g(\bar{x}) $

It has an inclination towards infinity at $ y\to \infty$ and towards negative infinity for $ y\to -\infty$ and is thus onto $R$.

Then $\exists y_{0}$ which solves the equation. But $T_{y} = 3y^2 -2y + (1+\bar{x}^2) $ has no non real roots.

This implies that $ \forall x$ the polynomial is injective.

Is there a problem with this argument?

I did not use the continuity of $g$ and since the question appears in my calculus course I initially thought it would require the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: Your argument is correct : a degree 3 polynomial $P$ such that $P'$ has no real root has a unique root. The implicit function theorem can be used to prove that this root $Y(x)$ smoothly depends on $x$, for insatnce if you want to compute $Y'(x)$.